# How to remove a package built from source that has the same name of another package?

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm running Debian 7.3 and I built Python 2.7.6 from source and it was installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` I used [checkinstall](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall) to create a .deb package so I can easily uninstall it later, the problem is that I named the package `python`, but if I try to remove it it'll remove all the other packages that depend on `python`, so now I removed the installed files manually but the package is still showing in Synaptic package manager and also if I run:

```
apt-cache show python
```

I can see the 2 descriptions, the one I installed and the default one, also in Synaptic I can see it under Status > Installed (local or obsolete).

So how can remove this package without removing the original python package ? it's showing 2 versions 2.7.6 (my own version) and 2.7.3 (the system's version), can I remove 1 version and keep the other ?

Comment: You replaced the distribution's package by yours. To go in the other direction, replace your package by the distribution's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just install the python version from the repositories. Lets assume the following:

```
apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: 2.7.6
  Candidate: 2.7.6
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.6 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.3 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stable/main i386 Packages
```

In this case, the package installed isn't available in any of the repositories. Then what we should do is downgrade the package using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install python/stable
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python=2.7.3
```

or

```
sudo apt-get -t stable install python
```

This will downgrade the package seamlessly. Next time append to the package some version name like this `python2.7.6` to prevent this.

Comment: `python2.7.6` is way to close to `python2.7`, which is an actual package in Debian. If you name it `local-python` or something like that, you will make it very clear its your locally-built version, and won't have to worry about accidentally replacing a distro package.

Comment: I would not recommend sticking a package built checkinstall into a debian system. chances it won't play nice with the rest of the system. Use standard Debian utilities to build such a package. Bear in mind you can't have a file which has the same name as that in another package, so two files both called `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python2,7` won't work.